# Meaning of все поголовно

Tags: словоупотребление

Recently, I came across this statement in a blog about the use of a Russian expression:

> Обычно подро́стки (практически **поголовно**) используют это
>   выражение.

... which I translated to mean: *Usually teenagers (almost **entirely**) use this expression*.

However someone told me that (1) this expression is considered somewhat dated and not very common in Modern Russian; and (2) that when used, it expresses a tinge of scorn or disapproval, like *the whole (damn) lot of them.*

Is this accurate?

Comment: Are you asking about практически поголовно or about все поголовно ?

Comment: I used все as a filler, since this is probably always used with groups of people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«Поголовно» simply implies that something is happening on a large scale, be it something negative or something positive.
Compare

> Наверное, они чуть ли не поголовно все наркоманы?

and

> Тогда мальчишки все поголовно увлекались футболом.

As you see there is nothing bad in being interested in footbal.

However, it may still be used with a relatively small group of people, e.g. a class, meaning "without exception".

Comment: Greg, would you mind translating your examples?

Comment: Sure. 1) Probably, the whole lot of them are drug addicts? 2) At that time all the boys without exception were passioanate about soccer.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, it's still in use.
2. Usually not. Consider also Latin "*per capita*".

The impression of some "scorn or disapproval" may originate from the meaning of this word in farming: *livestock capita* = *поголовье скота*. Nevertheless, applying either adjective *поголовный* or adverb *поголовно* to human-beings is OK.

Comment: So is it true that using it in the sentence I gave implies that the speaker doesn't approve of the expression in question?

Comment: @CocoPop "Практически поголовно" = "Nearly all of them". Sounds quite neutral for me.

Comment: Thank you! However, do you agree that it's not considered formal enough to say something like: Если не указано иное, новые правила относятся всем студентам поголовно. in a school announcement, for example?

Comment: @CocoPop I'd say "Новые правила _распространяются_ на всех учеников, если не указано иное". Such the formalities are: even saying "правила _относятся_" sounds a bit non-formal.

Comment: So поголовно would definitely not be used in this statement, correct?

Comment: @CocoPop Yes, you're right.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't grasp how `поголовно` is related to `per capita`. The only meaning of the word I have ever heard is `entirely` as @CocoPop mentioned, `(almost) everyone`, while `per capita` means `на душу населения`. It does not mean `everyone`. Consider this: you have a salary equal to $30 and I have $10. Then the per capita salary between us is $20, but it does not mean that everyone, or we entirely have a salary of $20. Though, I might be wrong with understanding the expression `per capita`, so correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: @user907860 In Latin "per capita" means "for each head". Don't confuse it with modern meaning.

Comment: ok, thank you, sorry, cannot remove the downvote

Answer (score 1):

Both things that person told you are true. The word "поголовно" is related to "поголовье скота" (cattle count).